# jQuery - copy field from table row and paste it to other fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the code bellow in order to copy the contents of a field from a SharePoint site.
(I mention SP as we are not able to edit the tags)

That field's data is in the format of `"name (department)"`.

Then I need to separate it to two columns, one for the name and one for the department.
Unfortunately, the tags don't have any ids or titles to help me pick the correct column, so I need to count the children of each row and append the result in the correct one.
However, my code is not working and as I am not that experienced with jQuery I cannot figure out why.

Although I can separate name from department I have two problems:

1. The data are pasted in every forth and fifth child for all the rows and not for that specific one.
2. All the data that are copied from the `$('tr td.ms-vb-user')` are repeated in the cells

e.g. if we have:

> UserA (DepartmentA)
>   UserB (DepartmentB)

Then all the forth children will be `(DepartmentA)(DepartmentB)` and all the fifth `UserA` `UserB`

Forgive me for my ignorance :)

Looking forward to your answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    FindTextToSplit();
});

function FindTextToSplit(){ 
    $('tr td.ms-vb-user').each(function(){
        var myField = $(this).text();
        var name = myField.substr(0,myField.indexOf('('));
        var department = myField.substr(myField.indexOf('('), myField.indexOf(')'));

        $("tr td:nth-child(4)").append(department);
        $("tr td:nth-child(5)").append(name);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution :)

After hooking up it the summary of the table and loop through each row instead of each cell, now it is working like a charm!

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    FindTextToSplit();
});

function FindTextToSplit(){     
    $("table[summary='TestList'] tr[class!='ms-viewheadertr']").each(function(){
        var myField = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
        var name = myField.substr(0,myField.indexOf('('));
        var department = myField.substr(myField.indexOf('('), myField.indexOf(')'));

        $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").append(department);
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").append(name);
    });
}
```